# How to get a preview of the HTML returned by a network requests?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I have the "new" version of Firebug, which is integrated into the web developer tools (Firefox 51.0.1 on MAC) - but now I am unable to get the returned result as answer from an Post Request (in this case Laravel).

[image: HTML source shown for network request]

Now I can only get the result as HTML content, not the rendered result (like in the "old" Firebug).

Any ideas how to change that? I dont find anything in the settings.

Comment: The "new version of Firebug" are actually the [Firefox DevTools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the request within the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) there will be a *Preview* side panel showing the HTML contents.

[image: HTML preview in Network Monitor]

**Update**
The preview was [removed in Firefox 55](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350229). It is [added back in Firefox 59](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353319) placing it within the *Response* panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - already found that out by myself. Little bit strange at the beginning when you use firebug for at least 10 years with the same interface ;)

Comment: But the latest versions of Firefox (~55) has removed the preview tab. Now it's very hard to identify errors :(

Comment: Yes, that was obviously removed in [bug 1350229](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350229) due to an obviously incorrect assumption. The preview will be added back in [bug 1353319](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353319). I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: still no preview, February 25, 2018.  What is the deal?

Comment: The feature is added back in Firefox 59, which will be [released on March 13](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar), so you just need to wait two more weeks. Alternatively, you can install the [Beta](https://beta.mozilla.org) or [Developer Edition](https://aurora.mozilla.org) of Firefox.

Comment: Using developer edition only got to 58b (without this feature). Guess I'll have to wait